# Is it safe to suspend a http servlet request in jersey?

Tags: java, asynchronous, jersey, servlet-3.0

Assuming a Jersey `ContainerResponseFilter` implementation like this:

```
public class MyFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public ContainerRersponse(ContainerRequest req, ContainerResponse resp) {
       if (shouldBeAsync(resp) {
           AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync();
           ....
       }
       return resp;
    }
}
```

Is this at all safe? Does Jersey assume that processing the request and producing the response content is happening on the same thread? What can happen if another thread attempts to modify the response object?

I thought I'd just ask before submerging myself into jersey code.

Comment: Did you ever find anything interesting on this topic?

Comment: No. But we decided to use resteasy instead, so my investigations wasn't that thourough.